# How to select a dynamic datepicker instance in order to extend it with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to control positioning of a jQuery datepicker element.  I like the solution offered at [How to control positioning of jQueryUI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818670/how-to-control-positioning-of-jqueryui-datepicker) for overriding the _checkOffset fn:

```
$.extend(window.DP_jQuery.datepicker,{_checkOffset:function(inst,offset,isFixed){return offset}});
```

However, this results in a 'window.DP_jQuery is undefined' error.  Upon inspection, I can see that the DP_jQuery object in the DOM gets named with a random string, like so: DP_jQuery_123456.  If I use this full name in the above code, it works wonderfully.

My question is whether there's a way to exend the _checkOffset fn for a datepicker instance without knowing before-hand what the instance name is?  For example, can I use some sort of wildcard to select all datepicker instances that begin with 'DP_jQuery_'?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out.  The best way to do this is like so:

```
$.extend($.datepicker,{_checkOffset:function(inst,offset,isFixed){return offset}});
```

If I understand correctly, window.DP_jQuery_123456 is a pointer to the object/function $.datepicker.  So it's simply easiest to extend the actual object, rather than try to figure out the name of the pointer to the object.