# jquery UI datepicker put button before the field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to have the button that pulls up the calendar in the JQuery UI datepicker before the input field? By default it is always put after the field. I tried `isRTL: true` but that also changes the prev/next buttons in the calendar.

Comment: Hope you may find answer from this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526500/getting-jquery-uis-datepicker-to-always-open-in-a-certain-direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least two ways to achieve this. One is as described by JMax. The other one is simply move the icon before the input box:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    ...
    buttonImage: "path/to/icon.png"
}).next().insertBefore('#datepicker');
```

See this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/william/rrcmq/1/.

Comment: This works! If class selector is used(e.g. `$('.date')` ), we can iterate each date field then `$(this).insertBefore( $(this).prev('input') );`

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to put a button that triggers the calendar like [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger) but on the left, you can easily add a button on your own and bind it an event:

```
$("#mybutton").click(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker( "show" )
});
```